# How to convert selected variables in a dataframe from numeric to factor using a loop

Tags: r

```
age (int) 27, 33, 50, 29
month_nov (dbl) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
default_yes(dbl) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
housing_yes (dbl) 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
```

This is just a sample I need to convert all the columns with datatype as numeric to factor without affecting variables with data type as integer.

Any shorter way to do this..

Comment: Shorter than what?  You haven't shown any methods.  And why would you want to convert numeric columns to factor?

Comment: @Dirty Sock Sniffer I am building a model that would undergo random forest algo and hence wanted to convert them to factors.The longer method for me was to convert each variable one by one to factor.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mutate_if` after creating a function to check whether the column `class` is `numeric` and not `integer`.

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x) !is.integer(x) & is.numeric(x)

res <- df1 %>%
           mutate_if(f1, factor)
str(res)
 # 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ age        : int  27 33 50 29 24
 #$ month_mov  : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1
 #$ default_yes: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1
 #$ housing_yes: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 2
```

---

For this, we don't really need `mutate_if`.  However the OP's input dataset seems to suggest that `dplyr` had made some inroads into that dataset.    But this can be accomplished with `base R` too.

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, f1)
df1[i1] <- lapply(df1[i1], factor)
```

Or by checking the `class` and doing a comparison on the type.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(class(x) == "numeric") factor(x) else x)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(age = c(27L, 33L, 50L, 29L, 24L),
  month_mov = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0), default_yes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), housing_yes = c(0, 
 1, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("age", "month_mov", "default_yes", "housing_yes"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey, is mutate_if function of dplyr?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Yes, it is a new convenient function introduced in the new version along with `mutate_at` and other stuffs.

Comment: Oh, Thank you, let me check my package version then. I am still using `R 3.3.0` and my `dplyr` version is `0.4.3` and can you give me one line brief on connection between `plyr` and `dplyr` and their loading sequence to console.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian `dplyr` is advanced version of `plyr`, but there are some functions in `plyr` that are not in `dplyr` and viceversa.  I think you will get a warning when you load plyr after dplyr, then you have to use `dplyr::summarise` or `dplyr::mutate` among the functions that are common.

Comment: Thank you so much, I installed `dplyr 0.5.0` and found `mutate_if` and `mutate_at` and other functions too. Could you please tell me where do you get these new update news from? Curious. Also I tried your above code its working, I added at the end `sapply(class)` to see if its converted after `mutate_if`. :) Thanks to make me learn about it.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Glad to know that the post helped you.  I just randomly check once in a week to see what functions are in the pipeline from the Hadleyverse group by visiting their github page so as to keep uptodate :-)

Comment: @richa1465: if this has helped you can mark your question as answered by clicking the tick mark., cheers http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers